# CakePHP: 3 levels deep associations not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp

In my app a user has a profile and a user can post comments and posts.

When viewing a list of comments for a post I want to show the name of the person that posted the comment. I have tried the following:

```
<?php if ( ! empty($post['Comment']) ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($post['Comment'] as $comment): ?>
            <li id="comment-<?php echo $comment['id']; ?>">
                <h3><?php echo $this->Html->link($comment['User']['Profile']['firstname'] . ' ' . $comment['User']['Profile']['lastname'], array('controller'=>'profiles','action'=>'view','userName'=>$comment['User']['username'])); ?></h3>
                <?php echo $comment['content']; ?>
                <?php echo $comment['datetime']; ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
        <p>No comments...</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But I get the following error: `Undefined index: User [APP/View/Posts/view.ctp, line 37]`

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

I have the following for the controller method:

```
function view ( $id = null, $slug = null )
    {   
        $post = $this->Post->find('first',array('contain'=>array('Comment','User'=>array('Comment','Profile')),'conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>Tiny::reverseTiny($id))));

        if (!$post)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException('404');
        }
        else if($post['Post']['status'] == '0') // 0=draft 1=open 2=open
        {
            if($post['Post']['user_id'] == $this->Auth->user('id'))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has NOT been published yet');
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotFoundException('404');
            }
        }

        if (Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title']) != $slug || $slug = null)
        {
            $this->redirect(array('id'=>Tiny::toTiny($post['Post']['id']),'slug'=>Inflector::slug($post['Post']['title'])));
        }

        $this->set(compact('post'));
    }
```

The model associations should all be correct as I can see the comments fine and see the profile info for the post itself, it's just the comments that don't show the profile info.

Thanks to all who can help.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$post['Comment']` as `$comment` in your foreach, whilst your user data isn't in `$post['Comment']['User']` but in `$post['User']`, so your call with `$comment['User']` won't work, since that index does not exist.

Use `debug($var)` in the future so you can see how your array structure looks like at any given moment.

Comment: Okies so what would be the best way to fix this issue? As `$post['User']` is the post user and I need to use `$comment['User']` as that is the comment user.

Comment: Put a `debug($post)` at the start of your code so you have a clear view of the array structure, from that point on you can probably figure it out. You can also put a `debug($comment)` in your foreach block, so you can see what information the foreach block contains. Hope you'll figure it out with this information.

Comment: If you go here: http://beta.favorr.me/posts/ugsdu_goushgsdug_usghu_sdfuhsuhu-1eL88Q you can see the debug information. I'm not understanding the fix though. If you could help. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @Cameron You didn't include the model User whithin Comment in `contain` statement. Use `'User'=>array('Comment' => array('User'), 'Profile')`

Comment: Okay that fixes it but now I have a pretty horrendous contain statement... `$post = $this->Post->find('first',array('contain'=>array('Comment'=>array('User'=>array('Profile')),'User'=>array('Comment','Profile')),'conditions'=>array('Post.id'=>Tiny::reverseTiny($id))));` Any ideas how to make it more efficient?

Comment: You can't really make the contain more _efficient_. If you want the data, you need the full contain parameter.  I would suggest breaking it up to multiple lines with indentation to make it easier to understand though.

Comment: One thing that does stick out though, is do you really need the Post->User->Comment model?

Comment: What's the point of the associations in the model then if I have to basically repeat myself in the controller contain call?